# How to correctly handle errors in PHP via phplint

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm very new to PHP.  I have a line of code on a server side script that opens a file:

`$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');`

When I run this code through phplint, it gives me the notice:

```
                $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
                            \_ HERE
==== 19: notice: unhandled error(s): E_WARNING
```

I tried creating an error handler earlier and specifically setting it to handle `E_WARNING` like this:

`set_error_handler("errorHandler", E_WARNING);`

But I get the same notice.  I'd like to do this correctly.  Is there some other mechanism to handle this error that `phplint` thinks is correct?

Comment: You could run a file_exists() before you do fopen()

Comment: @JohnP Right, but `phplint` wouldn't notice that the error would never trigger in that case.  Does that mean it's reasonable to ignore those sorts of warnings from phplint?  (Sorry if this is so simple).

Comment: I'm wondering about that myself. I don't use PHPlint so I don't know. Checking whether the file exists before you open it should be enough to stop errors in 99.9% of use cases. You could also use `is_readable`, kills two birds with one stone, so to speak

Comment: @JohnP looks like phplint is only trying to warn me in that case.  it doesn't mean I haven't handled the error correctly.  If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I can "check" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHPLint warning indicates that the function (fopen in this case) is documented as "raising" an E_WARNING if an error condition occurs.

If this occurs, then odds are that you will get an error message displayed in the console or on screen. Most programmers don't want this in production code and will silence the error by adding @ to suppress this warning or changing the php.ini (error_reporting).

PHPLint is just reminding you that you did not add the @. Lint would like your code to be more like:

```
$fh = @fopen($myFile, 'r');
// check $fh here
```

Obviously adding a file_exists() or is_readable() before the call would not silence PHPLint.

Ref: http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/manual.html?p=errors

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
"If the open fails, an error of level E_WARNING is generated. You may use @ to suppress this warning."

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's `is_readable()` method to see whether the file exists and is readable before reading from the file.

Manual entry : http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php

Answer (score 0):

You can silence the error using `@fopen`, and then check to see if the return value `=== FALSE` instead.